# accessing a variable created inside a method from another method in a python class

Tags: python

I want to access a variable created inside some method from another method. For instance:

```
class text():
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.txt = text

    def sp1(self):
        self.a = self.txt.split(',')[0]
        self.b = self.txt.split(',')[1]
        return self.a

    def sp2(self):
        return self.b
```

Now when I try to apply this like in:

```
T = text('I woke up early, it is school today')

print(T.sp2())
```

I get an error that `'text' object has no attribute 'b'`

I don't understand where the problem seems to be?

Comment: When you create `T`, `T.b` does not exist until `T.sp1()` is run. Therefore as as in the answer from quamrana, you need to do `T.sp1()` first.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you mean:

```
T = text('I woke up early, it is school today')
T.sp1()
print(T.sp2())
```

Comment: Aha, I understand now. The variable isn't created unless `sp1()` is called!

Comment: That's right. Its all there in the code you provided.

Answer (score 1):

So I guess the solution in this case would be to call `sp1` inside `sp2`

```
....

def sp2(self):
    self.sp1()
    return self.b
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not define `self.b` prior to calling it.

(Edited to remove false assumption that you can only define the attributes in `__init__`)

Comment: It's good practice to define them in `__init__`, but they don't have to be defined there.

Comment: You can 'define' new variables attached to an object at any time! Even from the 'outside'.

Comment: @JeremyHue Really? I guess you learn something new every day. I frequently got errors trying to attach attributes to the objects that were not defined in `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class text():
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.txt = text
        self.a = self.txt.split(',')[0]
        self.b = self.txt.split(',')[1]

    def sp1(self):
        return self.a

    def sp2(self):
        return self.b
```

Comment: I still need to call `sp1` before `sp2` so a new value is assigned to `self.b`

Comment: I changed the answer

Comment: actually, I didn't want them to be initiated inside  `__init__`

Answer (score 0):

class text:
def **init**(self, text):
self.txt = text

```
def sp1(self):
    self.a = self.txt.split(',')[0]
    self.b = self.txt.split(',')[1]
    return self.a
    
def sp2(self):
    self.sp1()
    return self.b
```